# Calendar in ionic modal throwing Uncaught in promise error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I need some help with making a calendar in my app. My Idea is to have a button with some text that when the user clicks on it, it opens a calendar but I keep getting this error.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting'isDateEnabled') TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'isDateEnabled')
```

**This is the code in HTML file:**

```
<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col size="12">
        <div class="buttons-wrapper">
          <ion-button fill="clear" id="kolendar" expand="block" datetime="datetime">
            <ion-icon slot="start" name="calendar-outline"></ion-icon>
            <p>Set delivery date<br/>
            <span>Set delivery lorem ipsum</span></p>
          </ion-button>
        </div>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>

  <ion-modal [keepContentsMounted]="true">
    <ng-template>
      <ion-datetime
        id="datetime"
        presentation="date"
        locale="sl-SL"
        [firstDayOfWeek]="1"
        color="vigros"
        [showDefaultButtons]="true"
        doneText="Shrani"
        cancelText="Prekliči">
      </ion-datetime>
    </ng-template>
  </ion-modal>
</ion-content>
```

**And this is the .ts file:**

```
  ngOnInit() {

    const isDateEnabled = (dateIsoString: string) => {
      const date = new Date(dateIsoString);
      if (getDate(date) === 25 && getMonth(date) === 11) {
        return false;
      }
      return !isWeekend(date);
    };

    const datetime = document.querySelector('ion-datetime');
    datetime.isDateEnabled = isDateEnabled;
  }
```

If I include the datepicker outside modal the app comnpiles normaly...

whats the cats? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: My guess would be your Query Selector sets your const Datetime to null. 
Maybe try something along the lines of
<ion-datetime isDateEnabled={{this.isDateEnabled}}>
</ion-datetime>

Answer (score 0):

[Suggest you review the lifecycles of angular.](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) At ngInit time the dom is not available.

Try moving the failing code to ngAfterContentInit

Comment: I tried this and this is what the browser console shows: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'isDateEnabled')
TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'isDateEnabled')